# Grafana/Elastic - Filter certain fields alone from the document and draw graph

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

**Problem Statement:**

Out of multiple fields from the elastic document, draw graph considering certain fields alone from the elastic document

There are documents in the elastic database in the below format at different timestamps.

```
{
    "Sensor_id": "Sensor_IDX_05",
    "company_name": "company_x"
    "freq_18.0": 415, # no. of packets
    "freq_19.0": 2262,
    "power_20.0": 98,
    "power_21.0": 1236,
    "power_21.5": 882,
    "power_22.0": 240,
    "@timestamp": "2024-02-20T04:12:28.000Z"
}
```

Trying to represent this data in Grafana using Heatmap with "Time Series bucket" data format.

Timestamps on the X axis, and fields like "power_*" and "freq_*" on Y axis. From the graph, we can visualize, at a given point of time, what are the buckets and number of packets in each bucket.

**Grafana Configuration:**

[image]

I have selected Raw Data as metric, it will get all the fields in the document and generate graph like below.

[image]

**Requirement:**

To generate graph for the fields that starts with "power_*" alone, rather than for all the fileds in the document.

Since the fields are dynamic, and power_x will grow in future, I cannot select the Metric Type "Max" and choose the field I want, as I need to manually add query everytime when encountering new field (say power_45.0).

Any help would be appreciated.